# document.getelementbyid returning null

Tags: visualforce, javascript

```
<apex:page controller="" showChat="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" standardStylesheets="false" docType="html-5.0" cache="false" title=""  >
   <apex:composition template="dsfdsf">
      <apex:define name="body">
         <head>
            <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="HTTPS://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/> -->


           <script>
               j$= jQuery.noConflict();
               j$(document).ready(function() {
                var a =   document.getElementById('{!$Component.page:template:frm:inputtext_OrgName}');
                alert('value' + a);

               });



        </script>
        <style>



        </style>
     </head>
     <!-- Jumbotron -->



  <apex:outputPanel id="outputPanel_Header" layout="block" styleClass="SectionHeader text-right col-md-offset-8"  style="padding-top:5px;">

        </apex:outputPanel>
        <div class="row" height="100%" style="padding-right:15px;padding-left:15px;">

        </div>
    <div id="dummyErrorPanel"></div>
    <!-- BEGIN ERRORS SECTION -->
    <!--           <apex:outputPanel id="outputPanel_ErrorMaster">
       <apex:outputPanel layout="block" id="outputPanel_Errors" rendered="{!errorCount>0}" styleClass="has-error" style="background-color: #FFFFCC;border: 1px solid #A94442;padding:20px;">

       </apex:outputPanel>
       </apex:outputPanel>
       <!-- END ERRORS SECTION -->

          <!--  Tabs -->
          <div class="panel with-nav-tabs col-md-4" >
             <div class="panel-heading tab-width" >
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>

             </div>
          </div>
  <div id="pageContent" class="jumbotron" style="border:1px solid silver;background-color:white;box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);margin-bottom:15px;margin-top:15px;padding:0px 20px 10px 20px !important;">
       <apex:form id="frm" html-role="form">
          <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="container" id="outputPanel_BkgndInfo" >
             <div class="col-md-8" >
                <h3 style="text-align:left; PADDING-bottom: 10px;color:#3980c6;"><strong>Background Information</strong></h3>
                <div style="border:1px solid silver;background-color:white;box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);resize: vertical;margin-bottom:15px;margin-top:15px;padding:0px 20px 10px 20px !important;">
                   <h4 style="text-align:left; PADDING-bottom: 10px;color:#3980c6;"><strong>Organization</strong></h4>
                   <div class="form-group required" style="text-align:left">
                      <label for="inputtext_OrgName" class="control-label" style="text-align:left !important;">Organization Name <span type="button" class="btn-default hbutton" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Legal Name of Business" style="font-weight:bold;">?</span></label>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery](https://jquery.com/) has more [concise mechanisms](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) (its tag line is "write less, do more") built in for finding elements than the underlying DOM API e.g. `document.getElementById` so best to use the jQuery version. And because of the Id prefixing of Visualforce, it is usually simpler to find elements by class than Id e.g.:

```
<script>
j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$(document).ready(function() {
    var a = j$('.orgNameMarker');
    console.log('input found = ' + (a.length === 1));
 });
 </script>

 ...

 <apex:inputText id="inputtext_OrgName" styleClass="orgNameMarker" .../>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the outputpanel id too.

Your code seems incomplete, so the below code might not work, but it should be like:

```
document.getElementById('{!$Component.page.template.frm.outputPanel_BkgndInfo.inputtext_OrgName}');
```

Comment: I tried adding it too .. still returns null

Comment: Sorry, I just realized it is dot not semicolon. Also, what I usually do, is on the page inspect the element, and that input should look something like id="j_id0:thefomr:ele1" this way if the element in the inspect window has 3, i know i need to put 2 things after the component